# How can I load a datatable in Batches

Tags: datatables

Hey I am trying to load values for my campaign table from Database and displaying it using Datatables. The output is divided into pages such as 15 records on each page. Now since the datatables are getting all the records at the time of loading, the page is taking too much time to render. So I need a way in which only 15 records at a time are fetched and more records will be fetched after I click on page 2 / next page. How can I achieve it?

Comment: You're looking for the datatables [server-side processing](http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html) example. Select the _AJAX_ tab in the source files table and then page through the table. You can see the data being updated in real time. In the example, one page of results is being fetched at a time, as oppose to the full data object.

Comment: @War10ck that should be an answer. :)